# Using stackview for positioning

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, uistackview

I am new to swift development. In portrait mode I want to display two buttons in each row. Totally I have three rows. But in landscape mode I want to reposition the buttons three in one row. Where I will have two rows with three buttons each. To achieve this I have used stackview in storyboard. Using stackview horizontal, vertical axis I was able to achieve this in landscape mode (Displayed three buttons in single row). But I couldn't achieve it in portrait mode.

Storyboard View:

1. In first stackview - contains two UIViews. First UIView will have button1, button2. Second UIView will have button3
2. In second stackview - contains two UIViews. First UIView will have button4, button5. Second UIView will have button6.

With this existing project I am unable to size classes also. So is there any way to achieve for these buttons with equal spacing and alignment on both orientations?

Comment: Your description is a little confusing... Manually layout your two arrangements and show us screen-caps of your goal.

Answer (score 0):

With multi-tasking capabilities, you really need to think in terms of view size, not landscape or portrait orientations.

You'll need at least *some* code -- you won't be able to do this with Storyboard layout alone. Here is one approach:

- Use a "container" vertical stack view
- add 3 horizontal stack views
- in "Landscape" orientation (view is wider than tall)

  - add 3 buttons to each of the first two horizontal stacks
  - **hide** the 3rd horizontal stack
- in "Portrait" orientation (view is narrow)

  - add two buttons to each of the 3 horizontal stacks
  - **show** the 3rd horizontal stack

To update the layout on size change - device rotation or split-screen multi-tasking, implement

```
func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

Here is a quick example:

```
class TwoThreeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var buttons: [UIButton] = []
    
    let containerStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 8
        v.distribution = .fill
        return v
    }()
    
    let statusLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        for _ in 1...3 {
            let v = UIStackView()
            v.axis = .horizontal
            v.distribution = .fillEqually
            v.spacing = 8
            containerStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        for i in 1...6 {
            let b = UIButton()
            b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            b.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: [])
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
            b.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
            b.backgroundColor = .red
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            buttons.append(b)
        }

        view.addSubview(containerStack)
        view.addSubview(statusLabel)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain containingStack
            //  top / leading / trailing
            //  with 20-pts "padding"
            containerStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            containerStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            containerStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // center the status label
            statusLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            statusLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        arrangeStacks(view.frame.size)
        
    }
    
    func arrangeStacks(_ size: CGSize) -> Void {
        
        // unwrap and make sure things were setup correctly
        guard let stk1 = containerStack.arrangedSubviews[0] as? UIStackView,
            let stk2 = containerStack.arrangedSubviews[1] as? UIStackView,
            let stk3 = containerStack.arrangedSubviews[2] as? UIStackView else {
                fatalError("Setup was not done correctly!")
        }
        
        // if wide (landscape)
        //  3 buttons in the first 2 horizontal stacks
        //  hide the 3rd horizontal stack

        // if narrow (portrait)
        //  2 buttons in each horizontal stack
        //  show the 3rd horizontal stack

        if size.width > size.height {

            buttons[0...2].forEach {
                stk1.addArrangedSubview($0)
            }
            buttons[3...5].forEach {
                stk2.addArrangedSubview($0)
            }
            stk3.isHidden = true
        
        } else {
            
            buttons[0...1].forEach {
                stk1.addArrangedSubview($0)
            }
            buttons[2...3].forEach {
                stk2.addArrangedSubview($0)
            }
            buttons[4...5].forEach {
                stk3.addArrangedSubview($0)
            }
            stk3.isHidden = false
            
        }
        
        statusLabel.text = size.width > size.height ? "Width > Height" : "Height > Width"
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { [unowned self] _ in
            self.arrangeStacks(size)
        }) { [unowned self] _ in
            // if you want to do something after size change
        }
    }
    
    @objc
    func btnTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        guard let b = sender as? UIButton, let t = b.currentTitle else {
            return
        }
        print("Tapped: \(t)")
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let vc = UIAlertController(title: "Please Note", message: "This is Example Code only. It should not be considered \"Production Ready\"!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        vc.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

The results:

[image]

[image]

[image]